# jQuery Custom Scrollbar doesn't scroll bottom well

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a chat service, everything works fine except for one little detail, the scrollbar. I'm using the jQuery Custom Scrollbar plugin.

It doesn't go to the bottom, sometimes it's does really well but sometimes it stuck in the half from the last message, I have been working in this detail for one week and I can't figure out what's the problem yet.

Here's my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>---</title>

    <!-- Main CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">
    <!-- Extra CSS -->        
    <link href="css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- All JS Scripts-->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.elastic.source.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/flowtype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cpg_smartphones_proto.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <!-- Perfect Scrollbar 
    <link href="css/perfect-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <script src="js/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>-->
    <!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css">
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie8.css" />
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if !IE]><!--><script>  
    if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) {  
        document.documentElement.className+=' ie10';  
    }  
    </script><!--<![endif]-->  
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">

<div class="row">
        <div id="chat_intro">
                <div class="chat_caller" onclick="goToChat()">
                    <h1>Enter</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div id="chat_box">
        <div id="chat_top" hidden="hidden">
            <div id="chat_header">
                <h4>Personal support</h4>
                <p>Find the best product for you.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="chat_avatar"></div>
        </div>


            <div id="chat_container">
                <div id="history_div">
                    <div id="history_mc">

                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>

        <div id="chat_footer">
                <textarea id="input_area" type="text" onkeypress="chatHandler(event)">                  
            </textarea>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#chat_box').hide();
            $('#chat_footer').hide();
        });
    </script>

    </script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

And now, the JS:

```
    function goToChat() {
    origin = BANNER_NAME + "_" + uid + metaData;

    $("#chat_intro").hide();
    $("#chat_box").show();
    $("#chat_top").show();
    $("#chat_container").show();
    $("#chat_footer").show();
    $("#history_div").mCustomScrollbar( {
        theme : "dark-thick",
        advanced : {
            updateOnContentResize : true
        }
    });
    document.getElementById('input_area').focus();
    chat();
    }
    function chatHandler(event) {
    // ENTER key
    var key;
    if (window.event) // IE8 and earlier
    {
        key = event.keyCode;
    } else if (event.which) // IE9/Firefox/Chrome/Opera/Safari
    {
        key = event.which;
    }

    InputInterface.restartTimeout();

    if (key == 13) {        
        chat();        
        $('#input_area').focus();
        event.keyCode = 0;
    }
}
function chat() {
    // Build request
    var chatText = "";
    if (!initialized) {
        chatText = "hi";
    }
    else {
        chatText = input_area.value;
        if(chatText.trim()=="")return;
        var userAnswer = USER + input_area.value + TIME + getTimeStamp() + TIME_END + FONT_END;
        history_mc.innerHTML += userAnswer;

        $("#history_div").mCustomScrollbar("update");
        setTimeout(function(){
                        $("#history_div").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", "bottom");
                    });
        $(input_area).val("");

        if(getUrlParameter("isMobile") == "true") hideKeyboard();

    }

    $("#deleteThis").remove();
    InputInterface.prepareSending(chatText);
    setTimeout(function(){history_mc.innerHTML += TYPING_MESSAGE; 
    $("#history_div").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", "bottom");});

    if(!initialized){
        InputInterface.flush();
        initialized = true;
    }
}
    //Start calling recursively getMsgId until the retries max out or succesfully get an Id
    function getResponse(json) {
    start = new Date().getTime();
    processRetries = 0;
    responseRetries = 0;
    getMessageId(json);
}
function displayResponse(response) {
    $("#deleteThis").remove();
    history_mc.innerHTML += BM_INI+ response_number +BM_FIN + response + TIME + getTimeStamp() + TIME_END + FONT_END;
    $("#history_div").mCustomScrollbar("update");
    setTimeout(function(){
                if (DEBUG) console.log("#conv"+response_number);
                $("#history_div").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", "#conv"+response_number);
                response_number++;
                },250);
    document.getElementById('input_area').focus();
}
```

I hope you can shine me with you jedi powers, thank you so much.

Greetings.

Comment: Are you able to differentiate the messages that cause the problem and the others, or is it really random? (If you repeat a text that caused it, does it do it again)

Comment: It is random, sometimes with short messages and sometimes with long messages.